Why is this white line between the two vertical boxes?
I have two colorboxes which should appear vertically close together, but without any white line in between. The MWE shows the problem. Is there a better solution for this task?
I am not interested to know how to put boxes vertically on the other. I just needed to know how to prevent the white line appearing between the vertical boxes. Manually it can be done with \vspace*{-1pt} between the minipages. But that seems not elegant enough.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\Rueckenbreite}
\setlength{\Rueckenbreite}{50mm}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\Rueckenbreite}
\colorbox{LightCyan2}{%
\begin{minipage}[c][0.3\paperheight]{\Rueckenbreite}%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textcolor{black}{\raisebox{-0.28\Rueckenbreite}[0.28\Rueckenbreite]{\centering\huge Some longer text}}}
\end{minipage}}%

\colorbox{LightBlue2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.3\paperheight][c]{\Rueckenbreite}%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textcolor{Black}{\raisebox{-0.28\Rueckenbreite}[0.28\Rueckenbreite]{\huge Other text}}}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{minipage}  

Why is this white line between the two colorboxes? How can it be prevented?

\end{document}



Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

Output added, please see above. Please not the thin white line. With \vspace{-1pt} it can be resolved. But why does it exists at all?

When you can't use \baselineskip, LaTeX adds \lineskip between the bottom and top of the two boxes.

You want to locally disable the interline skip, besides simplifying the code.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\Rueckenbreite}
\setlength{\Rueckenbreite}{50mm}


\begin{document}

\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{%
  \colorbox{LightCyan2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\Rueckenbreite]{0.3\paperheight}
      \huge\centering Some longer text
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}\par\nointerlineskip
\rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{%
  \colorbox{LightBlue2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\Rueckenbreite]{0.3\paperheight}
      \huge\centering Other text
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\end{document}



It's the interline glue. To avoid this, you can use \offinterlineskip after the first \begin{minipage}:
\begin{minipage}{\Rueckenbreite}\offinterlineskip


Thank you, that is what I need. To do this manually would need several \vspace*{-1pt} to let vanish the white line between the boxes.

No, please, no! The declaration \offinterlineskip is global, you possibly want \par\nointerlineskip.

@egreg Would you know if there is there a counterpart command for horizontal alignment  if the boxes were placed side by side?

@DDS You don't insert a space.

@egreg Yes, but when magnified, a slight white line still appears. That does not happen for the vertical case when I use nointerlineskip.

@DDS Without an example, it's impossible to say. Anyway, it's not connected with the present question

@egreg Perhaps it's worth a posted question. Thanks again.
